# Baking wheat and dairy-free bread with only dry yeast

Tags: bread

I am going to try and cook my own wheat and dairy free bread. It says use dry and fresh yeast.

Can I use only dry yeast, and if so how much more do I have to use?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use dry yeast.  Fresh or cake yeast, active dry yeast, and instant dry yeast are all interchangeable, although differing amounts may be required, and they have different requirements for proofing or activation.

If you are using traditional active dry yeast you will want to [proof it](http://www.thekitchn.com/baking-lessons-how-to-proof-ye-94555).

According to the [Fresh Loaf](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/faqs/baking/yeast), you can substitute dry yeast for fresh yeast at a ratio of 1:3 by weight:

> Professional bakers often use fresh yeast. If you encounter a recipe
>   that uses fresh yeast, divide the weight by 3 to calculate the proper
>   amount of instant yeast to use.